# Логика MySQL базы пользовтелей и новостей

Tags: mysql

Внутренняя почта, пользователи, новости...

Есть таблица пользователей, есть таблица с новостями (сообщениями).
Как правильно поступать:

Есьт одно сообщение записанное в таблицу базы `новости`, и показано всем.

Как записать статус что сообщение прочитано? Нужно создавать 10 000 однотипных сообщений для каждого пользователя в таблицу сообщений? (если стоит задача рассылка новости как сообщения с отслеживанием статуса прочтения).

Comment: Как предполагается помечать сообщения прочитанными. У вас есть некое событие чтения каждого конкретного сообщения или всех сразу, по факту входа пользователя в раздел сообщений ? Если первое - то заводим таблицу id-пользователя,id-сообщения при прочтении вносим в нее запись (факт ее наличия и есть "прочитано"), если второе - храним в пользователе дату-время последнего прочтения сообщений

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно знать это по каждому пользователю, то вам в самом деле нужно будет помечать в БД по каждому пользователю факт прочтения сообщения.

Пусть у вас есть таблица с тремя INT для строки, новости, пользователя и временная метка. Это примерно 16 байт на строку без учёта индексов. Или примерно 300 килобайт на 10000 пользователей включая индексы.

Сколько таких записей поместится в один гигабайт - посчитайте сами.

Comment: То есть по факту предлагаете писать 10 000 одинаковых сообщений в таблицу сообщений отличающуюся только id получателя?

Comment: Окей, можно под каждую новость сделать отдельную таблицу, в которую писать только ID пользователя. Сколько вы на этом сэкономите, 100 или 200 килобайт на десять тысяч пользователей? При этом насколько вы себе усложните жизнь? Стоит оно того?